# ORACLE using TO_DATE to check if item is within last hour

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, where-clause

I have a query that I am trying to use `TO_DATE` to check if `ERROR_DT` is a data that is within one hour of the current time
Here is what I have so far

```
   SELECT BERROR_DT FROM SomeTable
WHERE ERROR_DT>=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') -1, 'fmMM/DDfm/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
```

`Error_DT` has a value of (e.g.) `5/18/2020 6:45:15 PM`

When I run this I get

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

I followed the said link and it still is not working. How would I fix this so that I can still remove all 0s in front of the month and the date?

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with. `TO_DATE( SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') -1` should be `sysdate - 1`

Comment: Why are you storing `DATE` values in a `varchar` column to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest converting the date string to the corresponding `date` value, then do the comparison:

```
select berror_dt
from sometable
where to_date(error_dt, 'fmMM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') >= sysdate - interval '1' hour
```

Bottom line, you should fix your data model and store dates as a date-like datatype rather than as a string. The above predicate is not efficient, because the conversion needs to be executed for each and every value of `error_dt` before the filtering applies, hence defeating an existing index on the column.

Comment: Thank you! this really helped me out and you had the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously wrong thing you're doing is applying `TO_DATE` to `SYSDATE` which is a function that returns `DATE` datatype.

What you could do is to subtract `sysdate` and `error_dt` (I presume its datatype is `DATE` as well) and see whether difference is less than 1 hour. As difference of two dates is number of days, you have to divide it by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day).

Something like this:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = ' dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ss am';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (id, error_dt) as
  2    (select 1, to_date('18.05.2020 10:30:15 PM', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ss am') from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 2, to_date('18.05.2020 05:20:55 AM', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ss am') from dual)
  5  select t.id, t.error_dt, sysdate
  6  from test t
  7  where sysdate - t.error_dt < 1 / 24;

        ID ERROR_DT                SYSDATE
---------- ----------------------- -----------------------
         1  18.05.2020 10:30:15 PM  18.05.2020 11:02:24 PM

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If ERROR_DT is a DATE value you just need to use something like

```
SELECT BERROR_DT
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE ERROR_DT >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR
```

or if you prefer to use old-fashioned pre-INTERVAL calculations

```
SELECT BERROR_DT
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE ERROR_DT >= SYSDATE - (1/24)
```